# How to stop script when "if" is false

Tags: bash

I'm learning BASH scripting, and I've got a problem. I wrote a generator, that checks if there is script with same name as given and if not it makes one, makes it executable and gives it proper shebang. But it doesn't work. I wanted it to exit when there is already one script with that name. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash

clear

echo "Name the script"
read name
echo "What shell? (bash/sh)"
read type
if [ -e ./$name ]

then
    echo "You already have that script"
    read    
    exit
else
    touch $name
    chmod 755 $name
fi

case $type in
"bash") echo '#!/bin/bash' > $name ;;
"sh") echo '#!/bin/bash' > $name ;;
*) echo "I don't know what do you want" ;;
esac
vim $name
```

Comment: You have `vim` at the end. Is this intended?

Comment: This looks like it should work. In what way is it not working?

Comment: As a side note, you should both check `-x` and `-e` (or better yet `-f`). Because if `-e` checks out, the script can still not have execution permission (check with `-x`). The exit should work here, but specifying an exit code is better practice (e.g. `exit 1`) although not necessary.

Comment: @EtanReisner I have in same directory script called `foo.sh` when it should tell me about it, and exit. but it doesn't. It tells me that after the `case` instruction goes and modifies it.

Comment: In the same directory as what? The script above or the directory you are in when you run the script? If you add `set -x` to the top of this script what do you see when you run it and give it `foo.sh` as the script name?

Comment: Perhaps you have a space in the filename or in a parent dir. Always quote your variables (well not always but it can't hurt). So try `if [ -e "$name" ]`. By the way, your title doesn't correspond with your script.

Comment: Does your system have an `etc/shells` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an extra `read` which is holding you up:

```
if [[ -e ./$name ]]
then
    echo "'./$name' already exists"    # <<<< always report the name
    # read      <<<< This is the line which is causing problems
    exit 1   #  <<<< indicate there was an error
else
    touch "$name"
    chmod 755 "$name"
fi
```

Quote filenames incase they contain embedded whitespace (you don't need them around variables if you use `[[ ]]`.

Also note that the `#!` line for `sh` is wrong (you are using `bash` for both)

Edit:
If you have `/etc/shells` on your system, this is a good exercise in using `select` menu.  Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Name the script: " name

if [[ -e ./$name ]]
then
    echo "'./$name' already exists"    # <<<< always report the name
    # read      <<<< This is the line which is causing problems
    exit 1   #  <<<< indicate there was an error
else
    touch "$name"
    chmod 755 "$name"
fi

declare -a shells
i=0
while read shell
do
    if [[ $shell != \#* && $shell != "" ]]
    then
        shells[i++]="$shell"
    fi
done < /etc/shells

PS3='Please select the shell: '
select type in "${shells[@]}" QUIT
do
    echo "You selected $type"
    if [[ $type == QUIT ]]
    then
        exit 2
    fi
    break
done

echo "#!$type" > "$name"

vim $name
```

You might also consider using `$EDITOR` rather than hard-coding `vim`.